# joomla issue:please help

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Hello I am having a problem with my joomla code

when I try xxxxxxxxxindex.php?option=com_blast&task=ccis this is going to the controller function ccis and when I tr  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxindex.php?option=com_blast&task=ccim?data=123 this is going to the function display, I want this to come to the function ccis, how can I do this ??

whats wrong in my joomla

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is decipherable for a Joomla expert, but it isn't for me.

Comment: Not really a joomla issue if he actually used ?data instead of &data (see my answer). But I agree that the question is not written very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&data=123` instead of `?data=123`. In your URL you get the following arguments:

- option=com_blast
- task=ccim?data=123

As you see, data is not a separate argument since you are not using `&` to separate it from the previous argument.